# Python 3 - CSV writer loop won't close after CSV reader reaches end of file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, writer, reader

I'm trying to create a program that splits large CSV files into smaller ones. I've got the function working great, except it doesn't ever close the last file, which means it never finishes writing to that file. Here's what I've got:

```
import csv

length of original file = 1000 rows
length_of_new_file = 100  # rows


def file_splitter(file_name, desired_length):
    with open("{}".format(file_name), 'r') as original_file:
        header = original_file.readline()
        file_reader = csv.reader(original_file,dialect='excel')
        file_count = 0
        new_name = 'split_file_test'
        loop = 0
        while file_reader:
            with open("{}{}.csv".format(new_name, file_count), 'w', newline='') as new_file:
                new_file.write(header)
                csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',')
                for line in file_reader:
                    if loop == (desired_length-1):
                        csv_writer.writerow(line)
                        new_file.close()
                        file_count += 1
                        loop = 0
                        break
                    else:
                        csv_writer.writerow(line)
                        loop += 1


test_file = 'zlotsacontacts.csv'

file_splitter(test_file, length_of_new_file)
```

I have tried adding new_file.close(), but no matter where I put it the last file never seems to get closed. I've also tried different logic in the outermost while loop, like:

```
while file_reader != '':
```

and

```
while file_reader not None:
```

but from what I can find, the CSV module can't recognize None values. I'm not sure what I can do to close this loop!

Comment: EDIT - I was hoping to be able to do this without looping through the file twice. If it can't be helped, it can't be helped, but that was a goal starting out. Sorry for not mentioning that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with open` will automatically close the file when it is finished.

The `while` loop is getting caught in an infinite loop as the condition it is checking is simply `while file_reader`

`file_reader` is in existence so it will remain true.

A better approach is to use a loop that takes into account the number of files.

something like:

```
while file_count < number_of_files:
     ...
```

or as an example:

```
num_files = 5

count = 0

while count < num_files:
    print(n_files)
    count += 1
```

This way the while loop will break when it finishes iterating over all the files and ultimately close the last one

If you need to find out how many rows are in the file you can count them like so

```
import csv

with open('lines.csv') as lines:
    l = csv.reader(lines) # will read in larger files much better
    row_count = sum(1 for row in l) - 1 # -1 to not count the header row, if it exists.
print(row_count)
```

Comment: That's an elegant and simple way to solve the problem. The issue I run into (which could definitely still incorporate this idea) is that I don't know how long the files will be, and I'd like the length of the generated files to be dynamic.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you would want to use `csv.reader` if you are working with larger files.

Answer (score 0):

I should have taken a bit more time to think it through. By moving the 'for line' to be the outermost loop, I can check to see if there's a new file (and delete it, once I'm done with it), which solves the endless loop problem:

```
def file_splitter(submitted_file, desired_length):
    with open(submitted_file, 'r') as original_file:
        header = original_file.readline()
        file_reader = csv.reader(original_file, dialect='excel')
        file_count = 0
        new_name = 'a_file_test'
        loop = 0
        new_file = None
        csv_writer = None
        for line in file_reader:
            if new_file is None or loop == 0:
                new_file = open('{0}{1}.csv'.format(new_name, file_count), 'w', newline='')
                new_file.write(header)
                csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',')
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
            loop += 1
            if loop == desired_length - 1:
                new_file.close()
                file_count += 1
                loop = 0
```